# Static linking impossible on the host system 'i686-build_pc-linux-gnu'

Tags: linux

I am install cross compiler on beagleboard-xm . I got error - Static linking impossible on the host system 'i686-build_pc-linux-gnu'
what is solution for that ?

Answer (score 0):

more information needed.

for now, try disabling the option to statically link in the menuconfig as per http://sourceware.org/ml/crossgcc/2012-01/msg00017.html

quote:

> > in the menuconfig you should not select
> >     "Build Static Toolchain (EXPERIMENTAL)" in the "Toolchain Options" menu.
> >     This should make sure that CT_WANTS_STATIC_LINK=y is *not* used in your .config

they're reffering to OSX code, and without knowing what YOU'RE trying to do, we can't help you further.